# A script changes the source code of class. Why can the effect not be observed in the same console or test, where the script was run?

Tags: properties, pytest, python-class

I have written a script, that automatically adds a property to a class.
It works, but currently I can not test it.

The code is shown below, but can also be seen on GitHub.
See the class [*Cat*](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/tree/main/proj/classes/animals/cat),
the [script](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/tree/main/proj/scripts/prop)
and the [tests](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/blob/main/proj/scripts/prop/test).

The script does mainly two things:

- It creates a file with rudimentary code for the new property.
- It appends the property imports (which are in a separate superclass, to make this possible).

(E.g. creates [*whiskers*](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/blob/main/proj/classes/animals/cat/properties/whiskers/__init__.py)
and appends
[*CatProperties*](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/blob/main/proj/classes/animals/cat/properties/__init__.py).)

The script works for the practical purpose it was written for. But its effect is not immediate.
Running the script and trying to access the new property in the same console will fail.

[image]

But it works when I open a new console:

[image]

As a consequence of this lag, I can not write a test function for the script.
See `test_created_prop` [on GitHub](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/blob/main/proj/scripts/prop/test/_test.py).
(It also contains assertions, that proof the script has successfully run.)

I would like to know, if there is a good way to test the script.

Also, I would like to know the reason for the lag.
(I suppose, there is something to learn about Python here.)

### class *Cat* and its properties

#### class *Cat*

This is the `__init__.py` in folder `cat`.

```py
from proj.classes.animals.cat.properties import CatProperties


class Cat(CatProperties):

    def __init__(self, number_of_front_legs=2, number_of_hind_legs=2):
        self.number_of_front_legs = number_of_front_legs
        self.number_of_hind_legs = number_of_hind_legs
```

#### superclass *CatProperties*

This is the `__init__.py` in folder `cat/properties`.

```py
class CatProperties:

    from .clawnum import clawnum
    from .pawnum import pawnum
    from .claws_per_paw import claws_per_paw
```

(In the same folder is a `name.py` with a list of all property names, which is needed by the script.)

#### example property *clawnum*

This is the `__init__.py` in folder `cat/properties/clawnum`.

```py
def clawnum(self):
    return self.number_of_front_legs * 5 + self.number_of_hind_legs * 4
```

### script *create_property*

The script uses some Bottle templates to create or update files.
Mainly, it creates the init file for the new property. (Like the *clawnum* example shown above.)
It also uses the list of names in `properties/names.py` to update *CatProperties* and the list of names itself. This means, that new versions of these two files are created, based on the appended list of names.

```py
import os
from bottle import template
from importlib import import_module


def create_property(path_string, name):

    path_list = path_string.split('.')

    ############################################################################

    this_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    proj_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(this_folder))
    view_folder = os.path.join(this_folder, 'views')

    # existing properties folder
    properties_folder_list = [proj_folder, 'classes'] + path_list + ['properties']
    properties_folder = os.path.join(*properties_folder_list)

    # current names
    names_module = import_module(f'proj.classes.{path_string}.properties.names')
    names_list = getattr(names_module, 'names')

    # target folder
    target_folder = os.path.join(properties_folder, name)

    # files
    target_init_file = os.path.join(target_folder, '__init__.py')
    target_test_file = os.path.join(target_folder, '_test.py')
    update_names_file = os.path.join(properties_folder, 'names.py')
    update_imports_file = os.path.join(properties_folder, '__init__.py')

    # views
    target_init_view = os.path.join(view_folder, 'target_init.tpl')
    target_test_view = os.path.join(view_folder, 'target_test.tpl')
    update_names_view = os.path.join(view_folder, 'update_names.tpl')
    update_imports_view = os.path.join(view_folder, 'update_imports.tpl')

    ############################################################################

    context = {
        'name': name,
        'class_name': path_list[-1].title(),  # folder name in title case
        'path_dots': path_string,
        'names': names_list
    }

    ############################################################################

    assert name not in names_list
    names_list.append(name)
    os.mkdir(target_folder)

    with open(target_init_file, 'x') as f:
        f.write(template(target_init_view, context))

    with open(target_test_file, 'x') as f:
        f.write(template(target_test_view, context))

    ############################################################################

    with open(update_names_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(template(update_names_view, context))

    with open(update_imports_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(template(update_imports_view, context))
```

(The version [on GitHub](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/blob/main/proj/scripts/prop/function.py) is slightly more complicated, because it can also delete a property.)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `create_property` your code imports the `animals.cat` module.

Because the module is already loaded and exists within the existing python interpreter session, subsequent calls provide a reference but do not inspect/reload the module.

By manually reloading after calling `create_property` you will see your changes.

```
import importlib 

importlib.reload(animals.cat)
```

Comment: You are right, that `'proj.classes.animals.cat' in sys.modules.keys()` is true after running the script. But the reloading does not work.

Comment: @Watchduck can you update your original post to include the code you're running?

Comment: I am running the `create_property` script shown above. What are you missing?